# How to hide environment variables for passwords in Postman

Tags: postman

I want to hide environment variables in Postman. I am not sure that Postman has the ability to hide the environment variable. Any idea on this feature?

Comment: This is [requested feature since 2014](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/824), but looks like Postman developers have not so much care of it as it will have security problems anyway. There's more recent feature request [6639](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/6639)